# Android TimerTask SetColorFilter of Button

Tags: android, colors, timer

this is my first Question, i hope i do it right.
I need to change the color of some buttons in a specific interval.

I decided to do it with the Colorfilter, because the setBackground method makes the Button look ugly.

The Problem is the following:
If i set the ColorFilter within a Runnable, it is **not working**.

But:
Setting the ColorFilter in the onCreate or click method is **working**.
And:
Setting the BackgroundColor with setBackgroundColor within the Runnable is **working**.

I forgot to mention, that it is all working fine if i run it on an emulator with android 4.1 but not with 2.3.3.

Any ideas? Here is the code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }


    int counter = 0;
    Button b = null;

    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    final Runnable doit = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            if ( counter % 2 == 0) {
                b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
                b.setBackgroundColor(0xffff0000);  // working
                //b.getBackground().setColorFilter(0xFFD2691E, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);   // doesnt work
            }
            else {
                //b.getBackground().clearColorFilter(); 
                b.setBackgroundColor(0xff00ff00);
            }
            counter++;
        }
    };

    public void click(View view) {
        // configure timer 1
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                handler.post(doit);
            }
        };

        timer.schedule(task, 1111, 1111);
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried runOnUiThread?

Comment: y just tried it (runOnUiThread(doit) in run() of timertask). it is not working too. i guess im in the ui thread, because i can change the backgroundcolor.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with imageviews.
I found a solution, you have to call the invalidate()-methode:

```
ImageView img =(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myimageview);
img.getDrawable().clearColorFilter();
img.invalidate();
```